# Android Studio Stop Autospace after keyword

Tags: android, android-studio

Android Studio started inserting a space automatically after I press enter to autocomplete a reserved keyword. Is there anyway to stop this? I'm too used to pressing Space with my thumb after typing a word in code and this creates double the amount of spaces needed, and that too only after keywords.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by going to Preferences, then Editor > Code Style > Java. Then, click the Spaces tab, and scroll down to the reserved keywords that you care about, and make sure that the box is unchecked for each of them.